# Telnet timing out

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

I am working on a project for a class/internship. In it, I need to configure a router to accept telnet. The connection is just timing out.

To explain, I have an unmanaged switch between the router I need to telnet into and where I am telnetting from. However, with it being unmanaged, I doubt this is the problem. To show commands, here they are, though with altered ip addresses for security. The real ips are public, and I need a telnet to be able to be done from anywhere:

```
access-list 100 permit tcp any eq 23 any eq 23
!
enable password xxxxxx
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 127.12.168.5 255.255.255.128
 ip access-group 100 in
 ip access-group 100 out
 no keepalive
!
line vty 0 4
 access-class 100 in
 access-class 100 out
 exec
 exec-timeout 0
 password xxxxxx
 login
```

Any help to explain this would be much appreciated. I do have the ability to remote into the device that manages the router, so time is not a problem. As long as I am on, I can work on it.

Thanks in advance for any help able to be provided. I can provide more of the script if needed, though I started with what is relevant to my knowledge. However, like with what I provided, the ip addresses will be altered for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, school work questions are off-topic here, but I'll make an exception in this case:

1. Remove access-list 100 and all the access class/group statements.  The way you've written the access list, you require both the source and destination ports to be 23.  Telnet clients use a ephemeral source port greater than 1024 (greater that 49152 for Windows), so nothing will pass your access list.
2. The good news is you don't need an access list.  Just add this line under the vty statement:

> ```
> line vty 0 4
> transport input telnet
> ```

This will allow telnet access to the device.

If you do want to restrict access to only certain IP addresses, you can configure a standard access list like this:

```
ip access-list standard TELNET-ACCESS
! this allows a single host
permit 1.2.3.4
! this allows a whole /24 subnet
permit 1.2.3.0 0.0.0.255

line vty 0 4
access-class TELNET-ACCESS in
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks for responding despite my mistake of putting it in wrong area. I assume I am supposed to put it in the main stack exchange site if this is incorrect.